# Transferring Data from Oracle to MySQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, oracle, arabic

The Scenario is i have Oracle Database on Server and I made one web service in C#.NET and Transferring Data Into MySQL.

When i execute Web service it show data correctly on web browser.

```
[[{"'N'":"N","ILOM_SEQUENCE":32543,"LG_NUMBER":7595013,"LG_STATUS":"N","LG_AMT":500.0,"CUST_S_NAME":"سيف بن حمد بن عبدالله السليماني للتجارة","LG_DATE_FROM":"2015-08-19T00:00:00","LG_DATE_TO":"2015-08-21T00:00:00"}]]
```

Above you can see the response while i am trying to save data in mySQL all Arabic data goes ??????

when i print query it's shows correct data

```
CALL updateWebLog('pro_raffd_lg_prc', '[[{"N":"N","ILOM_SEQUENCE":32543,"LG_NUMBER":7595013,"LG_STATUS":"N","LG_AMT":500.0,"CUST_S_NAME":"سيف بن حمد بن عبدالله السليماني للتجارة","LG_DATE_FROM":"2015-08-19T00:00:00","LG_DATE_TO":"2015-08-21T00:00:00"}]]
```

after inserting json in database all Arabic gone

```
[[{"N":"N","ILOM_SEQUENCE":32543,"LG_NUMBER":7595013,"LG_STATUS":"N","LG_AMT":500.0,"CUST_S_NAME":"??? ?? ??? ?? ??????? ????????? ???????","LG_DATE_FROM":"2015-08-19T00:00:00","LG_DATE_TO":"2015-08-21T00:00:00"}]]
```

C#

```
mConnection.Open();
mCommand = mConnection.CreateCommand();
mCommand.CommandText = "CALL updateWebLog('" + type + "','" + xmlData + "');";
mCommand.Connection = mConnection;    
mCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
mConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Clarity needed as to what the problem is. You imply that Oracle has no trouble storing UTF-8 characters, while MySQL cannot.

Comment: yeah every thing is fine in Oracle and C#.NET Side, and i am using utf8 - utf8_unicode_ci in mySQL database.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: well I tried from C# to insert your data, and It worked I got arabic. Could there be some problem in the updateWebLog procedure? Have you tried to simply insert the xmlData into a test-table to verify it get correct?